# App crashes when requesting location and user does nothing

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have a button that uses the user's location to search around them. If they have not granted/denied permission to use their location yet, it requests the permission

Relevant code:

```
func updateLocationStatus(){
    locationEnabled = CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    appLocationEnabled = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
}

@IBAction func searchNearby(sender: UIButton) {
    updateLocationStatus()
    if appLocationEnabled == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied {
        //Show an alert to let them know they've denied location permissions
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if appLocationEnabled == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined || 
        appLocationEnabled != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse &&
        appLocationEnabled != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways{
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    else{
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}
```

It works fine when used normally. However, if you let the "Allow app to use your location [Don't Allow] [Allow]" alert sit there for about 5 seconds, the app crashes. The line jumped to in Xcode causing the error is

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

and the error provided is

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xsomeaddress)

I don't even know where to begin to fix this because the error tells me nothing and the functionality works perfectly fine, except for when you do nothing too long

Comment: Does the backtrace provide any helpful information?

Comment: Yes, it actually did. Turns out since I call this function as long as authorization is not determined, the searchNearby function is repeatedly called when the dialogue pops up until a stack overflow occurs. I thought the instructions would run sequentially (ie code execution stops on requestAuthorization until an answer is determined) but it seems this is not the case. Thank you for your suggestion, I never knew backtrace was a thing in xcode. Please reply as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the backtrace provide any helpful information? In the console, you can type bt at the prompt when Xcode breaks. Alternately, you can take a look at the debug navigator.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will solve this question. Make sure to add the appropriate key-value combo in your Info.plist.

Kind of like this:

[image]

Also you might want to set a break point to make sure that location definitely has been enabled.

To start finding the location, you should also configure the `desiredAccuracy` and `distanceFilter` properties of the location manager and then call the `requestLocation()` or `startUpdatingLocation()`.

Comment: I have the Privacy - Location Usage Description and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription strings set in my Info.plist. I never request Always Usage so I don't have that description